# How to Get all Ip and Mac address from the yml file in python?

Tags: python, automated-tests, yaml

```
EthernetClient:
     Windows:    
        ip: 192.168.1.152
        mac_adr: ‘X4:81:C7:BD:46:04'

     Windows_Extnd:    
        ip: 192.168.1.151
        mac_adr: 'X4:81:C7:BD:47:04'
        
WifiClient:
    Windows:    
        ip: 192.168.1.154
        mac_adr: 'X4:81:C7:BD:47:05’
    MAC:    
        ip: 192.168.1.3
        mac_adr: 'X4:81:C7:BD:47:06’
        
    IOS:    
        ip: 192.168.1.4
        mac_adr: 'X4:81:C7:BD:47:07’
```

This was the Yml file. From which i need to get ip and mac_adr for all keys.
I reached upto get the all data

```
import yaml
a_yaml_file = open("../Test/example.yml")
parsed_yaml_file = yaml.load(a_yaml_file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

print(parsed_yaml_file["EthernetClient"])
print(parsed_yaml_file.get("WifiClient"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some issues with you `.yml` file

- There's spacing at your last line `mac_adr: 'X4:81:C7:BD:47:07’`
- You started with `'` but end with `

**test.yml**

```
EthernetClient:
  Windows:    
    ip: 192.168.1.152
    mac_adr: ‘X4:81:C7:BD:46:04'
  Windows_Extnd:    
    ip: 192.168.1.151
    mac_adr: 'X4:81:C7:BD:47:04'

WifiClient:
  Windows:    
      ip: 192.168.1.154
      mac_adr: 'X4:81:C7:BD:47:05'
  MAC:
      ip: 192.168.1.3
      mac_adr: 'X4:81:C7:BD:47:06'
  IOS:    
      ip: 192.168.1.4
      mac_adr: 'X4:81:C7:BD:47:07'
```

**ExecutionScript.py**

```
import yaml

with open("test.yml", 'r') as f:
    valuesYaml = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    print(valuesYaml["EthernetClient"])
    print(valuesYaml.get("WifiClient"))
```

Finally here's how you get the value

---

As per requested, below's how you get the full list of IP

```
import yaml

with open("test.yml", 'r') as f:
    listOfIp = []
    valuesYaml = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    
    for clientType, clientValues in valuesYaml.items():
        for attr, value in clientValues.items():
            if 'ip' in value:
                listOfIp.append(value['ip'])

print(listOfIp) # ['192.168.1.152', '192.168.1.151', '192.168.1.154', '192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.4']
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please suggest to get only ip and mac_adr to print using for loop. It helps for me to validate the ip and macaddress in UI

Comment: @MahendraVengalam Updated the post as per requested, let me know if this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks This was useful for me and working fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MahendraVengalam Please do not forget to tick on the green tick to accept my answer, happy coding!